# DbContext.AddAsync sets owned property as null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, owned-types

I have table with owned entity as below:

```
public class Audio
{
  public Guid Id { get; }
  public VoiceInfo { get; }
}

public class VoiceInfo 
{
  public VoiceProvider Provider { get; }
  public Language Language { get; }
  public Gender Gender { get; }
  public string Name { get; }
}
```

with mapping:

```
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.VoiceInfo, v =>
{
    v.Property(x => x.Gender).HasColumnName(nameof(VoiceInfo.Gender));
    v.Property(x => x.Language).HasColumnName(nameof(VoiceInfo.Language));
    v.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName(nameof(VoiceInfo.Name));
    v.Property(x => x.Provider).HasColumnName(nameof(VoiceInfo.Provider));
});
```

When I create instance of Audio passing VoiceInfo I call

```
DbContext.AddAsync(audio);
```

then

```
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

throws an exception with message:

> ...Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Language'...

What is more interesting after call DbContext.AddAsync(audio) the VoiceInfo property from
Audio instance is set to NULL. This means that exception is valid but why after adding audio instance into context owned propety is set to null ?

I added some check before and after calling AddAsync() using:

```
var entry = Entry(audio);
var entityState = entry.State;
var ownedPropertyState = entry.Reference(x => x.VoiceInfo).TargetEntry.State;
```

Before:

Both entityState and ownedPropertyState are detached which is valid (?) - they do not exists  from context perspective.

After:

entityState is Added

ownedPropertyState throws and exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Are language and Gender etc. Enumerations or entities?

Comment: Just want to verify - are you calling DbContext.AddAsync(audio) with the 'await' keyword?

Comment: Yeah I did await the call. Gender and langauge are enums

Comment: Using `Add` instead of `AddAsync` could be a workaround: please see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7303#issuecomment-270195773) and [this](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/DbContextAddAsy-sets-an-ox2mq9vGRR6h5UEuI_SqoA?s=u)